# Full Width Transparent Textarea input

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a note application using HTML5 and CSS. While trying to take input from the user, I would like that the textarea is full width (100%) and would be transparent.

So, basically, the text area should be transparent and page should just show a white cursor, and there should be no overflow.

If someone could point me to saving and clearing the note, that would be great too.

Comment: Can you provide your current HTML and CSS?

Comment: `<textarea style="width:100%;color:#000;font-size:5em;"></textarea> `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on the image you have posted, wrap the textarea inside a container.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text-container {
  background: #4492E0;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

textarea {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  resize: none;
  border: 0 none;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 5em;
  outline: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <textarea>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Why in the CSS is the `textarea`'s `color` set to `white`? Shouldn't that be `transparent`?

Comment: Maybe. I just set it to transparent. White is on the focused textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Saving is a whole other thing, and should probably be a new question.

```
textarea {
    background:transparent;
    outline:none;
    border:none;
    width:100%;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just slam { width:100% } on the textarea you usually end up with a textarea that overflows its container. That since the textarea’s width will be 100% + padding + borders. You need to counter the padding and borders.

The absolute easiest way to do that is to **add padding to the wrapping element**.

> The width of the input is 100% of its container + 1px + 1px (borders) + 4px + 4px (padding). In other words the width is 100% + 10px; Therefore we give the fix class an extra 10px padding to the right.

```
    <!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <style>
  label { padding: 0; marign: 0; display: block; }
  textarea { width: 100%; border: 1px solid #333; padding: 4px; }
  .the-fix { padding-right: 10px; }
 </style>

</head>

<body>
 <label class="the-fix">
  A good-looking textarea with a 100% width
  <textarea></textarea>
 </label>
</body>
</html>
```

> for transparency just use CSS DUDE----

```
<textarea style="color: black; background-color: transparent;">Your text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your "**textarea**" in anyway you would like and apply these styles.

```
textarea{
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%; /* optional */
}
body {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* optional change it to your height */
  padding: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle; /* removes whitespace as textarea is inline element */
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="">Sed augue ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada adipiscing, dui. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. Suspendisse faucibus, nunc et pellentesque egestas, lacus ante convallis tellus,
  vitae iaculis lacus elit id tortor. Curabitur blandit mollis lacus. Quisque ut nisi. Cras varius. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis.</textarea>
```